# Next JS - How to fix Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3003 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete]

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js

I am new to Next JS.
I can't build my application locally. When I enter the **npm run build** command I get the following errors :

```
...
_currentUrl: 'http://localhost:3003/data/menus.json',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  response: undefined,
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3003
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1148:16) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3003,
  config: {
    url: 'http://localhost:3003/data/menus.json',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.4'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
...
```

Et à la fin du log

```
...
info  - Generating static pages (771/771)

> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /ar
        /ar/classic
        /ar/minimal
        /ar/standard
        /ar/vintage
        /de
        /de/classic
        /de/minimal
        /de/standard
        /de/vintage
        /en
        /en/classic
        /en/minimal
        /en/standard
        /en/vintage
        /es
        /es/classic
        /es/minimal
        /es/standard
        /es/vintage
        /fr
        /fr/classic
        /fr/minimal
        /fr/standard
        /fr/vintage
        /he
        /he/classic
        /he/minimal
        /he/standard
        /he/vintage
        /zh
        /zh/classic
        /zh/minimal
        /zh/standard
        /zh/vintage
    at C:\Users\PC\OneDrive\Documents\lab\samara\laravel\node_modules\next\dist\export\index.js:487:19
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\PC\OneDrive\Documents\lab\samara\laravel\node_modules\next\dist\telemetry\trace\trace.js:60:20)
    at async C:\Users\PC\OneDrive\Documents\lab\samara\laravel\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:833:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\PC\OneDrive\Documents\lab\samara\laravel\node_modules\next\dist\telemetry\trace\trace.js:60:20)
    at async C:\Users\PC\OneDrive\Documents\lab\samara\laravel\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:707:13
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\PC\OneDrive\Documents\lab\samara\laravel\node_modules\next\dist\telemetry\trace\trace.js:60:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (C:\Users\PC\OneDrive\Documents\lab\samara\laravel\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:77:25)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
Arguments: C:\Users\PC\.node\corepack\yarn\1.22.15\lib\cli.js build
Directory: C:\Users\PC\OneDrive\Documents\lab\samara\laravel\shop
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/workspace for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

The **npm run dev** command works without any problem. So locally the application has no problem. But when I go to production, I want to build I get these errors above.

Here is my **server.js** file:

```
// server.js
const { createServer } = require('http');
const { parse } = require('url');
const next = require('next');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3003;
// when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
      // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
      const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true);
      const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl;

      if (pathname === '/a') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/a', query);
      } else if (pathname === '/b') {
        await app.render(req, res, '/b', query);
      } else {
        await handle(req, res, parsedUrl);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err);
      res.statusCode = 500;
      res.end('internal server error');
    }
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`);
  });
});
```

And my **package.json** file

```
{
  "name": "@samara/shop",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3003",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node server.js"
```

If you need another file to check let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow - Is it possible that you are requesting `http://localhost:3003/data/menus.json` before the server is up? Where is this being called?

Comment: Please provide the code for one of the failing pages.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's the best way but in my case I run `npm run dev` then run `npm run build` and the error stops happening
then stop the dev and run `npm run start`

you can also add a try catch in the api call `http://localhost:3003/data/menus.json`
if you are calling in a `getStaticProps` function, you can in the catch set the revalidity to 1 second if you need to revalidate

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This doesn't really help - npm run build only succeeds because the dev server is running in the background. As soon as you exit the dev server then the same calls will fail when doing npm run start as well

Answer (score 0):

(i know this was posted a long time ago) Try using the port thats given inside of the error message. For example, for the error you would experiencing the port would be `3003` (the `port: 3003,` line tells you it). I had this error too and I just changed the port in my browser to the port given.

Comment: Post some code that shows how to do this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Theres no code to add. You just change the port in your browser.